# Mapping of static resources (html, js and css files ) in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, deployment, war

Basically I am trying to deploy a war file in Tomcat, that serves request like :
**http://localhost:8080/war-file-name/app/{app-name}/{lang}/**

There are multiple applications with multiple languages but the resource files (i.e. index.htm, css, and js files) are same. But the request tries to look into the folder structure as

war-file-name -> app -> {app-name} -> {lang}

I want to know how can I configure deployment descriptor ( web.xml ) or context.xml to use the same resources for all the requests, so as when a request needs to access with this url pattern, it automatically being redirected to use the static resources in some folder (say Resources) inside war.